# sqlalchemy.event.listen not found event "after_create"

Tags: python-3.x, events, sqlalchemy

I have a table Test and want`s to add a constraint for column 'progress'

```
class Test(Base):
__tablename__ = 'test'

id = Column('id', INTEGER, primary_key=True)
name = Column('name', VARCHAR(30))
progress = Column('progress', VARCHAR(4), server_default='0')


event.listen(
Test,
"after_create",
DDL("ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT "
    "cst_test_progress "
    " CHECK (progress like '[0-9]')")
)
```

this code returns error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No such event 'after_create' for target '<class '__main__.Test'>'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 9):

[`after_create`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents.after_create) is a `core` event, not an `ORM` event, so it doesn't accept an ORM class as it's `target` arg. From the docs:

> **target** – the MetaData or Table object which is the target of the
>   event.

It needs the table that your ORM model represents, not the model. An example solution might be:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Test.__table__, 'after_create')
def receive_after_create(target, connection, **kw):
    connection.execute(
        "ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT "
        "cst_test_progress "
        " CHECK (progress like '[0-9]')"
    )
```

Comment: This answer fixed it for me, i used `__tablename__`  instead of the correct `__table__`